# Bitrise build fail issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cicd, bitrise

I'm using Bitrise to generate builds directly.
I have Notification Service Extension in my project with One signal push notification.

❌  ld: framework not found Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension
❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The project is in native not flutter.